# Как сделать Status Bar белым, а иконки на нём тёмными на Android?

Tags: android, xml

Нужно сделать как на картинке и желательно через styles.xml. Вот так:

[image]

Уже пробовал

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
```

styles.xml выглядит так

```
<resources 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<style name="TransparentStatus" parent="@android:style/Theme.AppCompat.Material.Light">
    <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" tools:targetApi="m">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<style name="StatusBarWhite" parent="AppTheme">
        <item name="android:windowLightStatusBar" tools:targetApi="m">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="lollipop">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
```

Вы также можете установить его в коде:

```
View yourView = findViewById(R.id.your_view);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
    if (yourView != null) {
        yourView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LIGHT_STATUS_BAR);
    }
}
```

Если нужно сбросить изменения, очистите флаг:

```
yourView.setSystemUiVisibility(0);
```

Comment: Это правильная поправка для lollipop, но на marshmallow это не работает, увы

Comment: Обновил ответ. Можете попробовать

Comment: Проблема была в фреймворке, который я использовал - он задавал свою тему перед показом Activity. Спасибо, я тоже сделал через код